# Query in circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Consider a 20 Ω resistor which is connected to a 10 V battery, the work done by the battery would be equal to the Voltage X Charge (W=VQ) so each coloumb of charge would have 20 J of energy, now when "going" through the resistor the charge would have to do 20 J of work so it have 0 J of energy then how would the charges flow?

Comment: I believe you mean eV, not J. I dont see an issue with the model you presented. Charge flows through a resistor and lose energy while doing so. What is the problem?

Comment: My query is that after going through the resistor, it has 0J of energy so how does it flow

Comment: Well, where is the charge at that point?

Comment: the charge has passed through the resistor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isnt entirely clear to me where you are getting stuck but I will take a guess. You see the circuit as having a battery, a resistor, and 2 wires and you probably have a schematic drawn to this effect. You are confused about how after the electron loses all of its energy in the resistor it is still able to travel down the wire. That would be a problem except you are interpreting the schematic as I have described wrong.

There is only a battery and a resistor. There are no wires in a schematic. Wires have length and resistance. Those things drawn as wires in a circuit schematic have zero length and zero resistance. As soon as the electron loses its energy in the resistor it is at the positive terminal of the battery and gets it all back. (Well... batteries are more complicated than this, but you get the idea)

But wait! In real life you do have wires, what now? Well, real life wires have resistance. After your electron passes through the resistor it hasnt lost all of its energy. It still has some to go and it loses it going through the resistance of the wire back to the battery. So you can just replace your wires in the schematic with very low resistance resistors and you are good to go.